# Update column if calculation on two other select is greater than

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, calculus

Well, that's hell of a question.

Here is in a way what I would like

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT (less, more) FROM tempTable WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if( ($row[1] - $row[0]) / 75  <= 1.5 )
    {
        INSERT INTO tempTable (payValue) VALUES ('$ammount') WHERE id = '$user';        
    }
```

Question is, is it possible to make one of these two queries?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I mean, this works, but I would like to know if it is possible to make only one query for this whole monster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO tempTable (payValue)
    SELECT $ammount
    FROM tempTable
    WHERE id = '$id' and (more - less) / 75 <= 1.5;
```

EDIT:

Well, this is probably another situation where an `insert` should really be an `update`:

```
UPDATE tempTable
    set payValue = $ammount
    WHERE id = '$id' and (more - less) / 75 <= 1.5;
```

Use `insert` when you want to add new *rows*.  Use `update` when you want to change the values of existing rows.

If you do want another row, then it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO tempTable (id, payValue)
    SELECT id, $ammount
    FROM tempTable
    WHERE id = '$id' and (more - less) / 75 <= 1.5;
```

Comment: Well, if I put 

`INSERT INTO tempTable (payValue)
SELECT 85
FROM tempTable
WHERE id = 0 and ( more - less) / 75 <= 1.5;
`
in the left pannel in : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960a1/1

I got an error ( which is probably due to SQLFiddle and not MySQL itself ) :
Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: That did the trick. Two times today, thanks alot Gordon! You clearly made my day!